# Translation - Standard Software Menus and Terms Implemenation

Tags: object, menu, translation, standards

Most applications have quite a few predictable elements: "Home", "File", "About"...etc.

I was wondering if there is a standard "Helper" or fast implementation of translated common terms for applications.

Example:

---

Standard Software Menu Terms

-**Parent Term 1**

---French: Transliterated 1.

---Spanish: Transliterated 1.

---Chinese: Transliterated 1.

-**Parent Term 2**

---French: Transliterated 2.

---Spanish: Transliterated 2.

---Chinese: Transliterated 2.

/Stand Software Menu Terms

---

I thought some sort of object or XML could be utilized at installation or initialization. Given the evolution of modern software, I'd be surprised if some standard library of this sort didn't exist.

I searched quite extensively on this and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are standard translation "libraries". They are called Translation Memories or Terminology Databases. 
Microsoft has a default Terminology DB for all it's applications and it's open source.

https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Terminology.aspx

I think it's in the tmx or tbx format. Any real translation tool can handle them. I think OmegaT which is open source should be able to handle them too. Or you could try transifex. 
But if you work with a professional translation agency like e.g. [Supertext](http://www.supertext.ch) they can do this for you.

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no standard library. Probably, since applications usually share some common menu elements, but are specific in other menus.

Nevertheless, there are many tools, which ease the translation of culture depend contents. For Microsoft .NET applications, for example, [RESX Manager](http://resxmanager.codeplex.com/) may help you (my project). It builds up your own translation storage, in order to use common translations in several projects, by extracting contents from existing projects.